# Sonar 4.2 analysis both Java and JavaScript in same project

Tags: java, javascript, code-analysis, multilingual, sonarqube

I'm trying to analyse my **JEE** project with **Sonar 4.2**. It's a **multi-language** **JEE** project with **Java** and **JS**.

The plugins I've added to my **Sonar 4.2** are  : **Java 2.1** and **JavaScript 1.6**.

Recently, Sonar added the **multi-language** analysis, following the [doc](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner), I've removed the **sonar.language** from **sonar-project.properties**. But it still analyse only the **Java**.

I'm using **Sonnar Runner 2.3** in **Jenkins 1.555**. It analyse the project after every build.

Am I missing something ?

Edit : sonar-project.properties :

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=myProjectKey
sonar.projectName=MyProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path to the parent source code directory.
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional. If not set, SonarQube starts looking    for source code
# from the directory containing the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=src/main/java

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the content of your sonar-project.properties file ?

Comment: You can see my edit. There is no `sonar.language` as it's mentionned in the doc. And my JS files are in : `src/main/webapp/ui`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have Sonar looking for source code from src/main/java, so it won't find your js code.
Change it to:

```
  sonar.sources=src/main
```

Sonar will automatically make the java analysis from /java, and the javascript analysis from /webapp

Comment: We haven't configured sonar.sources and we are using sonar maven plugin, so it picks the src as the source folder but it doesn't pick our js files in 'resources' folder. I tried to add that in sonar.inclusions but no lock. From my understanding, maven plugin 3.0.1 should detect multi-languages am I right? Have I missed anything?