# How to configure qUnit in Sonar

Tags: javascript, qunit, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I need to configure my javascript qUnit test cases with sonar.

We have installed javascript plugin in sonar, and created lcov file using jscover,
and also updated sonar-project.properties file with source,test and lcov entries as below

```
sonar.sources=<ProjectWar>/target/<Project>/scripts
sonar.tests=<ProjectWar>/target/<Project>/test/js/scripts
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=<ProjectWar>/target/<Project>/test/jscoverage/lcov.dat
```

But we are not getting any unit test result in sonar.

Please give me steps how do we integrate qUnit with Sonar.

Below is the version

Sonar 4.2
Sonar Runner 2.3

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sonar 4.2 analysis both Java and JavaScript in same project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243351/sonar-4-2-analysis-both-java-and-javascript-in-same-project)