# calling Sonar analysis of Java and Javascript from Jenkins using Maven not SonarRunner

Tags: java, javascript, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a maven project(POM.xml) having java and Js files.I want to call sonar analysis from Jenkins.Please let me know how can I do to analyse both Java and Javascript files.I have done it for Java using sonar runner but the problem is Javascripts files are in different locations in Project directory.Hence, 
sonar.src=src/main/java will not work here.I think I need to go with Maven POM.xml to do the analysis as using POM.xml the project is getting build so analysis may be possible also?

1)I know using mvn sonar:sonar is possible but what I need to add in POM.xml for Sonar?
2)What I need to change in MAVEN settings.xml?
3)Please let me know the exact step by step if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Sonar are you using? If 4.2 or later, it is supported. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243351/sonar-4-2-analysis-both-java-and-javascript-in-same-project)

Comment: that ok but how to do using maven as using runner not possible because js files are in different location

Answer (score 0):

You can try this here

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

the website that has information to help you is this [one here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).